# How do I handle rabbitMQ message which is not delivered if I close a channel and client right after sending?

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm using `RabbitMQ` server with `Nodejs`.

I would sometimes use `RabbitMQ` a trigger for some function. So, I don't need to use client and channel anymore once I use those. That's why I close the client and the channel.

The problem is if I close those right after send a message, the message is not delivered successfully. I can definitely say that it's successful if there is 1 second sleep between sending a message and closing the channel and client.

How do I have to handle this case?

As I searched, there is no normal way to check if the message is delivered to the queue.

Any help and idea to figure it out?

Comment: There is a way to check for message delivery on the publisher side , please see this https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to check for message delivery on the publisher side , please see this [Publisher Confirms](http://rabbitmq.com/confirms.html)

You can also be notified if a message is not routed and then can take appropriate action as required.

Comment: I've come across that one! Let me try and update it!

Comment: Do you think that can I check if the message is sent perfectly? because if I'm gonna check the receiver get messages, it is able to make performance issue I guess.